# customizing my google maps info window content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to convert the following code to jquery or just make it work in order to save a ton of coding  for my info window content. I also am trying  to make the info window look very much like a mini html page with a picture etc. So I have been searching for this solution for  three weeks on here. I have watched many videos and cannot get any of it to work. The map works,the location lat long work everything works but the info window is terrible. Help please!

```
 <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
        function myMap() {
         var contentString = ' <div class="panel panel-info" Style="width:auto; height:auto;display: block; min-height: 134px;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0"">' +' <div class="panel-heading text-center" >' +'Sign Information' +
        ' </div >' +'<div class="panel-body">' +' <div style="float:inherit; width: 50%;">' +' </div>' +' </div>' + ' <div style="float:right; width:50%">' + ' <div class="k-content" style="width:200px">' + ' </div>' +
        '  </div>' +' </div >'
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(33.367302, -88`enter code here`.322125);
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var mapOptions = { center: myCenter, zoom: 6 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event)
         {
              placeMarker(map, event.latLng);

         });

         function placeMarker(map, location)
         {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
              position: location,
              map: map

         });
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content:( 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng() + contentString)

         });
         infowindow.open(map, marker);

         }

                    function geocode() {


                    }

                }
```

[the info window notice the pretty blue that's where I want all the content  not the big white  area , cant figure out how to fix it though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIh5D.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "the info window is terrible"?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, and a clear description of the problem.

Comment: You could use a site like jsbin.com, jsdiffle.net, codepen.io, to help us troubleshoot your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also,

just by glancing at your code I can see a code error and you are also forgetting to set your content.

make these adjustments...

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content :  'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>' + 'Longitude: ' + location.lng()+ '' });

infowindow.setContent(content);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

http://jsbin.com/tixini/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: No problem! If you feel like the answer was useful and helped you solve your problem, please accept it and/or upvote the answer as a way for others to review your question. See "Accepting Answers: How Does It Work?" here ...   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235